# Wrong Eureka instance port registration when server.port is random

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

The port that the eureka-client provides to eureka-server is wrong when the `server.port` is defined with `${random.int}`

- Example:
  When the server boots up the application port is set to 8050 but the Eureka instance have port 8064
- I configured the port to be random:

  ```
  server.port=${random.int(8500,8599)}
  ```
- I am expecting the `server.port` to be equal to the port on the eureka instance.
- Here's a diagram that represents briefly what I am trying to achieve
  [Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp6JG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that the Eureka instance port matches the randomly assigned server.port, you can explicitly configure the Eureka instance's port in your application's configuration. Here's how you can do it:

Add the following property to your application.properties :

```
eureka.instance.nonSecurePort=${server.port}
```

By setting eureka.instance.nonSecurePort to ${server.port}, you explicitly instruct the Eureka client to use the same port as the one assigned to server.port for registration with the Eureka server.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like this `server.port=0` ? I think it will work correctly

Comment: Yes, it works but unfortunately it doesn't fit my requirements as i need a specific port range

Comment: You can check another approach with SocketUtils from spring boot, if you really need to specify a range of ports